# How does Javascript match the parameters for the callback function in fs.watchFile()

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I'm attempting to recreate fs.watchFile() for a project, but I'm a bit confused on a particular subject. The question is about how does this callback function's parameters **curr** and **prev** gets populated?

```
fs.watchFile('message.text', (curr, prev) => {
    console.log(`the current mtime is: ${curr.mtime}`);
    console.log(`the previous mtime was: ${prev.mtime}`);
});
```

I've checked the node directory and analyzed the definition of the watchFile() function, but have found that it returns a single instance of stat object only.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js

Answer (score 0):

This answer will have a bunch of links to a bunch of code, which is not desirable in StackOverflow, but I think it's for the best in this case.

I think [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/watchers.js#L50) is the code you're looking for. Comes from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1354), where the listener (your function) is hooked on to the event 'change' on the `stat` variable, which is a `StatWatcher` (which is defined in the first file I [linked to](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/watchers.js#L50).

Comment: Could I ask if the values being passed into onChange(newstatus, stats) would happen to be 'change' and the listener function? Also I'm assuming self.emit is what's returning back curr and prev?

Answer (score 0):

The callback gets triggered when the 'change' event is emitted on the corresponding StatWatcher instance which is defined in [lib/internal/fs/watchers.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/watchers.js#L50). The StatWatcher is created in [lib/fs#line 1349](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1349) as part of the watchFile() function. The underlying implementation of StatWatcher is written in native code.

As you want to roll your own implementation it may be helpful to also have a look at the [inotify package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inotify) which implements monitoring file system events on a Linux System. Note, each "OS" has its concept of "file change" events.

Comment: Could i ask how stats is being passed in this line?
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1cdeb9f956a9f54dde7c6b1a792b97584acbfb8e/lib/internal/fs/watchers.js#L41